# Caching client-side XSLT imports in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer-7, xslt, msxml

I'm transforming an XML document with XSLT in Internet Explorer 7. My XSLT imports/includes -- I've tried both -- another XSLT with the following line:

```
<xsl:import href="utils.xsl" />
```

This results in an HTTP request for the included file every time the including XSLT is used, even if a reference to the parent XSLT is cached and re-used. IE sends a `Pragma: no-cache` header on each request for the import/include request.

Is it possible to prevent these repeated HTTP requests?

- Can I get IE to cache the file in the client?
- If not, can I get IE to send an "If-Modified-Since" header?

For completeness, here's the corresponding transformation JavaScript:

```
var XMLUtil = {

    // transforms the sourceStr using the given xslDoc
    transformString: function(sourceStr, xslDoc /*XMLDOM doc*/) {
        var sourceDoc = XMLUtil.loadFromString(sourceStr);
        var resultDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        sourceDoc.transformNodeToObject(xslDoc, resultDoc);
        return resultDoc;
    },

    // creates an XMLDOM document from a string containing XML
    loadFromString: function(xml) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        doc.async = false;
        doc.loadXML(xml);
        if (doc.parseError.errorCode != 0)
            throw "Error parsing XML: " + doc.parseError.errorCode;
        return doc;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responses to a [similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/msxml/thread/D8959D3E-CAFF-4B95-BC22-B95018CAC2F3) recommends setting [ForcedResync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms755472%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to false.

But [Qi Samuel Zhang's](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/qi%20samuel%20zhang/?type=forum&referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/msxml/thread/D8959D3E-CAFF-4B95-BC22-B95018CAC2F3) response cautions

> ForcedResync should work for most
>   cases, but the ForcedResync in MSXML3
>   has known issues to mitigate backward
>   compatibility, please use
>   MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0 when possible.